# Show form input without submitting

Tags: php, html, forms

I have seen forms before where as you type you can see your input at the side of the text field.

form code:

```
<form action="somewhere.html" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="fname" length="5" placeholder="your name">
    </form>
```

How would i show my name below this field (without clicking any submit button)?

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: _"Hope this makes sense?"_ It doesn't. Why would you want to show what's being typed next to what's being typed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML and Javascript to the following:

```
    <form action="somewhere.html" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" length="5" value="" onkeydown="javascript:showText();"> <br/>
        <span id="textShow"></span>
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var showText = function(){
         var oFName = document.getElementById('fname');
         var oTextShow = document.getElementById('textShow');

         if (oFName && oTextShow){
              oTextShow.innerHTML = oFName.value;
         }
    };
</script>
```

Tested and verified @ JSFiddle.  I've saved it for you to test.  http://jsfiddle.net/FkVfs/

Answer (score 0):

A keyboard event will be fired on every keystroke, while the submit event only fires when the form is submitted (usually via submit button).

Here's a reference on keyboard events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with javascript event listeners.  For typing, the `onkeydown` event will be helpful.  E.g.

```
<input type="text" name="fname" length="5" placeholder="your name" onkeydown="handleInput(this)">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/qxhX4/

```
$(document).on("keyup", "input[name=fname]", function() {
    $("span.fname").html($(this).val());
});

<form action="somewhere.html" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="fname" length="5" placeholder="your name">
    <span class="fname">Name will displayed here</span>
</form>
```

Simple made with jQuery. You just need to know about:

- Event-Handling
- Selectors
- some basic functions

I recommend http://learn.jquery.com and http://jquery.com if you'd like to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery:

html:

```
<form action="somewhere.html" method="get">
    <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" length="5" placeholder="your name"><div></div>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$('#fname').on('keyup', function() {
    var e = $(this);
    e.next().text(e.val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Recode/dk7MF/

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly, you are going to need to use Javascript.

Some things you should know.

PHP is a server side language, meaning you can't do anything with PHP unless you send some data to the server. Similar languages are ruby and python (similar in the sense they are server side languages)

Javascript is a client side language, meaning you can do things without sending data to the server.

Now, as an example, you have your HTML

```
<form action="somewhere.html" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="fname" length="5" placeholder="your name" onkeyup="diplayData()" id="fname">
</form>

<div id="information"></div>
```

Now you can use Javascript to do what you are looking for

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayData() {
        var data = document.getElementById("fname").value;

        document.getElementById("information").innherHTML = data;
    }
</script>
```

This is a basic example, you can do whatever you need with the data. I would suggest using jQuery, you tend to write less Javascript with it.